# Pandas combine two line charts into one

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

In Pandas, I have the following two statements, which are both producing line charts.

```
df_merged.loc[df_merged['Country'] == 'The United Kingdom', ['DateReported', 'NewCases']].set_index('DateReported').plot.line(figsize=(10,6))
```

[image]

```
df_merged.loc[df_merged['Country'] == 'The United Kingdom', ['DateReported', 'DailyVaccinations']].set_index('DateReported').plot.line(figsize=(10,6))
```

[image]
Both statements are identical. The difference is that in the first one I use 'NewCases' and in the second one 'DailyVaccinations' column is used

This is how df_merged looks like
[image]
There are 21 columns, but I am just interested in plotting 'NewCases' and 'DailyVaccinations'.

I would like to combine those two line charts into one. How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the original data

Comment: If you need assistance formatting a small sample of your DataFrame as a copyable piece of code for SO see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without more details, here is the general logic. Slice first the UK data, set your index, subset the columns of interest and plot

```
(df_merged.query('Country == "The United Kingdom"')
          .set_index('DateReported')
          [['NewCases', 'DailyVaccinations']]
          .plot.line(figsize=(10,6))
)
```

*No output as no data was provided*